# why is my textBox passing a blank string

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I am creating code for a code behind file for my assignment that involves creating a simple calculator.  I am running into problems and i narrowed it down to the string from the textBox.  When i try and set the textBox.Text to itself once the user clicks the equal button on the calculator, the calculators textBox becomes blank.  here is my code for my code behind file, don't mind the other code that is in it as I was originally just trying to see what parts of the loop were being run.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public partial class Assign2_Calc : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void ButtonEqual_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string inputStr = inputBox.Text;
    double value1 = 0;
    double value2 = 0;
    double result = 0;
    Calculator myCalculator = new Calculator();
    string operandsVal;
    string[] operands = Regex.Split(inputStr, @"(\+)(\-)(\/)(\*)");
    for (int i = 0; i < operands.Length; i ++)
    {
        if(i == 0 || i==4 || i==8 || i==12 || i==16 || i==20)
        {
          operandsVal = operands[i];
          //numMeh = Convert.ToInt32(operandsVal);
          value1 = 1;
          result = operands.Length;

        }
        else if (i == 2)
        {
            value2 = 2;
            result = 2;

        }
        else
        {
            switch (operands[i])
            {
                case "+":
                    result = myCalculator.Add(value1, value2);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    inputBox.Text = inputStr; //result.ToString();
}
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting it to show?

Comment: what are you trying to show us ?

Comment: right now I am trying to figure out why the string that is passed from textBox is not being sent.  When i set textBox.Text equal to it self, the textBox's text is blank.

Comment: You mean `inputBox.Text` of last line gets blank?

Comment: Can you post the aspx page where the textbox resides? And where are you setting "textBox.text to it self"?

Comment: If you change your code to:
protected void ButtonEqual_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string inputStr = inputBox.Text;
   inputBox.Text = inputStr;
}
Do you still see this behavior?

Comment: Put break point on the line `string inputStr = inputBox.Text;` and see what value is there on `inputBox.Text`. If it is blank, then `inputStr ` will be blank. I am guessing that for some reason `inputBox`'s `viewstate` is not loaded.